# Delete items in a folder in Outlook that are more than a day old

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to delete items that are more than 1 day old in a folder, DSP Reports, in Outlook, and I am asked to do this task using vba codes.

Right now, the codes run smoothly and no errors, but nothing is deleted, mails that came in yesterday and today after I ran the code. I used **F8** to trouble shoot but still no errors.

```
Sub DSP_Report_Deletion()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim i

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("DSP Reports")
Set oItems = olFolder.Items


For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    If DateDiff("d", oItems.Item(i).SentOn, Now) > 1 Then
        oItems.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next

'tidy up Outlook
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set oNs = Nothing
Set oOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, You're code is working fine for me.All email 2 days or older are deleted

Comment: It would be easier to setup an outlook rule to do this, especially if it has to run daily.

Comment: I know why now, I should have used `>=1` to include items that are 1 day old. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub DSP_Report_Deletion()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim i

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("DSP Reports")
Set oItems = olFolder.Items


For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    If DateDiff("d", oItems.Item(i).SentOn, Now) >= 1 Then
        oItems.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next

'tidy up Outlook
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set oNs = Nothing
Set oOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```